# Understanding the use of transducers in Ramda

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

Given the following code:

```
const objs = [
  {
    name: '1st',
    completed: false,
  },
  {
    name: '2nd',
    completed: true,
  },
  {
    name: '3rd',
    completed: true,
  },
]

const transducer = R.pipe(
  R.filter(R.propEq('completed', true)),
  R.map((obj) => {
    return {
      label: `${obj.name} (${obj.completed.toString()})`,
    }
  }),
)

const intoArray = R.into([])

console.log('-- working --')
console.log(transducer(objs))

console.log('-- not working --')
console.log(intoArray(transducer, objs))
```

When using the `R.pipe` form I get the expected result (two objects in an array both with a label field of the name and completed fields interpolated together)

However, with the transducer form I get an empty array. If I remove either the `R.filter` or the `R.map` (so only one operation is in the pipe) I get the expected result of having only that item in the pipe. However, it doesn't seem that I'm able to combine both of these operations.

**What am I missing here?**

A code pen with this code is available: http://codepen.io/rodeoclash/pen/EWJmMZ?editors=1112

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out in [this article](http://simplectic.com/blog/2015/ramda-transducers-logs/):

> We needed to change from pipe => compose because of the nature of
>   transducers. Although transducers can be composed directly, the
>   execution of the transformation is reversed. This means any time you
>   would use R.pipe for arrays, you would use R.compose for transducers,
>   and vice-versa.

[These](https://medium.com/javascript-inside/introduction-into-channels-and-transducers-in-javascript-a1dfd0a09268) [articles](http://jlongster.com/Transducers.js--A-JavaScript-Library-for-Transformation-of-Data) [are](https://medium.com/@roman01la/understanding-transducers-in-javascript-3500d3bd9624) also very useful. There is also pretty cool tool for inspecting stuff: [ramda-debug](https://github.com/sebinsua/ramda-debug).

```
const transducer = R.compose(
  R.filter(R.propEq('completed', true)),
  R.map((obj) => {
    return {
      label: `${obj.name} (${obj.completed})`,
    }
  })
)
```

Example in the [Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.23.0#?const%20objs%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7Bname%3A%20%271st%27%2C%20completed%3A%20false%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7Bname%3A%20%272nd%27%2C%20completed%3A%20true%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7Bname%3A%20%273rd%27%2C%20completed%3A%20true%7D%0A%5D%0A%0Aconst%20transducer%20%3D%20R.compose%28%0A%20%20R.filter%28R.propEq%28%27completed%27%2C%20true%29%29%2C%0A%20%20R.map%28obj%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20label%3A%20%60%24%7Bobj.name%7D%20%28%24%7Bobj.completed%7D%29%60%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%29%0A%29%0A%0Aconst%20intoArray%20%3D%20R.into%28%5B%5D%29%0A%0AintoArray%28transducer%2C%20objs%29).

Comment: So it seems that using a transducer reverses the order of the functions supplied to it?

My expectation was that using `R.pipe` with the transducer would have operated on it in the same order as using `R.pipe` without the transducer.